# Get only latest date from database (but get all rows with that latest date)

Tags: mysql, date

I'm creating a small application that displays openinghours.

It works like this: I generate a list of dates, then check the database if we are open or not.

The database `normal` contains:

```
day_of_week |  open  |  close |  since
   INT(11)  |  TIME  |  TIME  |  DATE
------------|--------|--------|------------
     1      |09:00:00|17:00:00|2013-01-09
     2      |08:00:00|18:00:00|2014-01-06
...
```

The since-date show since what date the openinghours are used (so I can look back in the past and get the right hours, as well as in the future.)

In my list of date I check if `since >= $date_in_list` and only display max value:

```
 SELECT *,MAX(since) FROM normal WHERE day_of_week = '2' AND since <= '2014-06-03'
```

This works fine, unless I have 2 hours with the same since-date (e.g. when we close at noon.)

So when I have data like this:

```
day_of_week |  open  |  close |  since
------------|--------|--------|------------
     2      |09:00:00|12:00:00|2014-01-06
     2      |14:00:00|18:00:00|2014-01-06
```

I would like to get both 09:00:00 - 12:00:00 and 14:00:00 - 18:00:00, but I can't seem to find the right query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a subquery? Something along these lines

```
SELECT *
FROM normal
WHERE day_of_week = '2'
    AND since = (
        SELECT MAX(since)
        FROM normal
        WHERE day_of_week = '2'
    )
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. Now I have: `SELECT * FROM normal WHERE day = '2' AND since = (SELECT MAX(since) FROM normal WHERE since <= '2014-06-03')`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `GROUP BY` clause like this

```
SELECT *,
       MAX(since)
FROM normal
WHERE day_of_week = '2'
  AND since <= '2014-06-03'
GROUP BY `since`,`open`,`close`;
```

Comment: This also shows previous hours, in this case it shows both the hours from `09:00:00|17:00:00|2013-01-09` and `08:00:00|18:00:00|2014-01-06` on 2014-06-03